# letsencrypt gitlab-omnibus causes nginx to crash

Tags: ssl, nginx, gitlab

I try to secure my gitlab omnibus site on Centos7 with let's encrypt and I have done the following steps

creating certficates

```
certbot certonly -c /root/letsencrypt-config/gitlab.ini
```

having the certificate I have been making changes to

```
 /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

like adding the following lines

```
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate']= "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_repo/fullchain.pem"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_repo/privkey.pem"
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config']="location ^~ /.well-known {\n alias /var/www/letsencrypt/.well-known;\n}\n"
```

running

```
gitlab-ci reconfigure
```

but at the end I get

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown "connection_upgrade" variable
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

so why the proxy do not work anymore?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having a similar problem.